# Quais são as maneiras de se criar arquivo html usando o php?

Tags: php

Queria saber quais as possibilidades que tenho de criar um `arquivo.html` usando o `php`.

No caso queria fazer com que um botão ao ser clicado gerasse isso para mim.

Por exemplo, tenho uma página no `php` e nela tem um botão. Ao clicar nesse botão, seria executado o código que criaria esse `arquivo.html` para mim num determinado diretório. Depois, seria possível acessar esse `arquivo.html` via `url`.

Quais as funções no `php` que eu preciso usar para criar tal arquivo? E se depois eu quiser alterá-lo, tem como?

Comment: Na verdade quando o codigo php é executado é gerado um html.Pra tu usar o html puro com php tu tem de criar um arquivo .php e ai tu pode usar codigo php e html.

Comment: Porque? Quero saber das possibilidades. Não é uma pergunta baseada em opiniões, até porque acredito que nã odevem ter muitas maneiras de fazer isso. Mas sempre pode ter mais de uma, mesmo que sejam poucas

Comment: Sim é possível! pode usar `file_puts_contents()` ou `fwrite()`(e as demais) pode fazer isso a partir de um template ou até de um textarea.

Comment: camarada, antes tinha visto esse file_puts_contents() e me interessei nele. Só que ele se assemelha ao fwrite (o único que eu conhecia)?

Comment: Boa sugestão, vou especificar melhor

Comment: Ficou bom! Muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma das maneiras rápidas de se aproveitar um PHP existente é essa:

```
<?php
   ob_start();                  // Isto bloqueia a saida do PHP para a "tela"

   ... tudo que você faria normalmente no PHP


   $gerado = ob_get_contents(); // Aqui capturamos o que seria enviado
   ob_end_clean();              // E limpamos, pois já está na string

   // neste momento, tudo que seria enviado para o cliente está em $gerado
   // e pode ser salvo em disco

   file_put_contents('arquivo.html', $gerado);
```

Se for construir uma aplicação um pouco mais caprichada, pode evitar o `output buffer` e gerar o HTML diretamente em *string*. Em vez de usar `echo`, por exemplo, pode concatenar desta forma:

```
<?php
     $titulo   = 'Meu HTML gerado'; // normalmente vai pegar de DB ou formulario
     $conteudo = 'Lorem Ipsum Batatas Doces';

     // Montamos nosso HTML no PHP, da forma que quisermos
     // \t é o tab, \n a quebra de linha
     $html  = "<html>\n";
     $html .= "\t<head>\n";
     $html .= "\t\t<title>".htmlentities( $titulo )."</title>\n";
     $html .= "\t</head>\n";
     $html .= "\t<body>\n";
     $html .= "\t\t<div>".htmlentities( $conteudo )."</div>\n";
     $html .= "\t</body>\n";
     $html .= "</html>\n";

     //... e vai montando o arquivo com variáveis etc
     // e depois salva

     file_put_contents('arquivo.html', $html);
```