# O que é um "output_buffer"?

Tags: php, terminologia, buffer

Lendo está [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184942/quais-s%C3%A3o-as-maneiras-de-se-criar-arquivo-html-usando-o-php#184948), me surgiu essa dúvida.

O que é um `output_buffer` ?

Comment: Um output buffer é um controle de saída ao qual você preenche o buffer com os dados que deseja enviar para o cliente. Já ao contexto dessa pergunta acho que se refere ao evitar de enviar dados sobre a pagina e enviar só a string concatenada.

Comment: Então, eu estou aprendendo php, e acho que vou precisar editar minha questão, para oferecer mais elementos relevantes a minha dúvida... Vi que no php tem um conjunto de funções ob_*, então eu preciso ver como vou editar para que a resposta seja mais voltada a linha prática no php... Peri, que estou dando uma lida para encontrar as palavras corretas....

Comment: @MagicHat tem alguma coisa que eu preciso melhorar na resposta?

Comment: man, tem um monte de resposta sua que preciso ler, mas gosto de avaliar bem... ainda não fiz... logo em breve o farei

Answer (score 5):

## *Buffer*

Quando falamos em *buffer* estamos falando de *buffer* de dados, não confundir com o termo usado em outros contextos mesmo na computação.

É uma área de memória reservada para armazenamento temporário de dados, em geral quando vai transportar de um lugar para outro.

O *buffer* pode ser uma simples variável com uma quantidade de bytes reservada ou alguma estrutura mais complexa.

*Buffer* é um conceito abstrato, ele se concretiza sempre através de um outro mecanismo, em geral uma variável.

## *Template*

O PHP trabalha com um sistema de gabarito de página. Então tudo o que não é código PHP é um texto que será mandado para o servidor HTTP.

Códigos PHP podem gerar novos textos dinamicamente inseridos na página, em geral como `echo` ou `print`.

PHP na verdade é uma linguagem que sempre gera um texto como saída. E tudo o que o código faz é determinar que código é esse.

Na maioria das linguagens um comando `print` ou `echo` imprimiria o texto na tela. O PHP pode trabalhar assim também. Mas o mais comum é ele fornecer páginas e outros elementos web para o servidor HTTP. Não faria sentido escrever na tela.

Tudo o que o código manda imprimir, inclusive as partes fora das *tags* `<?php ... ?>` é mandado para o servidor.

## Saída

Para evitar essa coisa picotada e dar mais flexibilidade podemos usar um *buffer* para armazenar tudo o que seria mandado para o servidor e podemos controlar quando enviar para o servidor, se é que queremos isto.

Na biblioteca do PHP tem a opção de ligar e manipular o conteúdo deste *buffer*. É o que foi feito naquela resposta.

Não tem muito segredo, na família de funções iniciadas por `ob_` temos como iniciar o *buffer*, pegar os dados e encerrar limpando ou soltando os dados para o servidor.

Se planejar bem dá para fazer o mesmo manualmente sem essas funções. Em vez de só imprimir você já vai manipulando uma variável criada especificamente para ser o *buffer*.

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php).

## Cabeçalho

No envio direto para o servidor você tem que pensar na ordem de fazer as coisas. Não pode mandar algo que precisa entrar antes do que já foi mandado. Por exemplo não pode mandar um *header* HTTP depois que começou enviar a página propriamente dita.

Com o *buffer* pode. Assim como se usar uma variável para concatenar todo o resultado do *script*.

## Exemplo:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    echo "1 : Hello\n";
    ob_start();
    echo "2 : Hello";
    var_dump(ob_get_clean());
    echo "3 : Hello";
?>
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VMY2UX). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hkdhftub-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/OutputBuffer.php).