# O que é e como funciona o output buffering?

Tags: php

O que é e como funciona o output buffering no PHP? Quando ele deve ser utilizado?

Comment: Isto responde? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184952/101

Comment: @bigown Sim, obrigado.

Comment: Percebo que você é um membro relativamente ativo, até me procurou no Linkedin dizendo o quanto gosta das postagens aqui no site. Acho que ainda falta você votar um pouco mais nas coisas que gosta. Nada errado se não quiser ou acha que não deve, mas ajuda classificar melhor o conteúdo bom se puder avaliar se é útil. Vote em assuntos que lhe são interessantes. Evite votar só em pessoas pessoas específicas (não que você esteja fazendo isto, só pra deixar claro). Pode saber mais em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/159/101. Você pode alertar também, veja a campanha aqui do lado ===>

Comment: @bigown Vou ficar mais atento a este detalhe, obrigado pela dica.